# How to change company iOS Developer account name?

Tags: apple-id, app-store-connect, developer-program

Is there anyway I can change company name from my iOS Developer account?

[image]

Like this for example where it says "By TARDIS59" is there a way to change it to "By Ashley Richards"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in any type of enrollment you cant change the sellers name, its permanent.

I would recommend you to [contact Apple Developer Support](https://developer.apple.com/contact/) and ask them if theres a way to change it, if its not you`ll have to buy a new enrollment and transfer your app.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: I thought so, just had to be sure, thanks for your help

Comment: Yes contact Developer Support, I did manage to easily change my display name through the Support Team. Thanks again.

Comment: How were you able to change your display name?

Comment: @SubjectiveEffect Contact Dev Support Team and explain that you would like to change your display name to your desired new display name.

Answer (score 2):

From [Apple's website](https://developer.apple.com/support/account/):

> To update the Apple ID and/or email address associated with your account, visit My Apple ID, click "Manage your account", and sign in with your current Apple ID and password. To update your address, contact information, or organization name, please contact us.